# Can't add a LSTM layer to model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I'm using python 3.5, and here are some packages that are installed:

- Keras 2.0
- TensorFlow 0.12.1
- Theano 0.8.2

Here is my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512, input_shape=(36, 45), return_sequences=True))
```

and here is error message:

```
TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.
```

Comment: The code seems okay to me, can you provide the whole stack trace?

Comment: Works fine with me too, my only difference is using Tensorflow 1.0.1 :) try upgrading tensorflow